# Why do I get to many outputs - python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find a number e.g 3:

```
number = 3

for x in range(0, 7, 1):
    x += 1
    if number == 3:
        print("3")
```

I get this output.

```
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
```

Comment: What is the problem? What are you expecting as the output?

Comment: An addition to the comment above, what is your code doing? Is `x += 1` supposed to be indented?

Comment: _"i am trying to find the number"_. From where? List?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are checking `number`, which is always `3`, not `x`, which is always 1 greater than the current loop iterator.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you want but you have bad indentation,indent it properly and it fixes your problem:

```
number = 3

for x in range(0, 7, 1):
    x += 1
if number == 3:
    print("3")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
number = 3

for x in range(0, 7, 1):
    if number == x:
        print("3")
```

try this